# Bypassing hosting provider country block

Tags: web-hosting, server, proxy

My Apache server is located in a farm that is blocking an entire country for the sakes of 'security' and avoiding an hacking attack. I'm trying to bypass this block, and would like help in doing so.

What I've thought of is creating a proxy with a different IP that will transfer all the traffic to my current Apache server that is being blocked.

Can someone point out direction on what is the best way to do this along with implications I should be aware of? Is there maybe a service that provides such a solution without actually needing to find myself another server that will redirect the requests?

Comment: In my experience, web hosts cost a lot of $. That make you the customer whom is always right. I'd suggest calling to complain. If you'd still like to do this look at 'Reverse Proxies': http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Comment: If the host is blocking a country, have you asked why? And do you know what country it is that they are blocking? I honestly never have heard of this issue ever, and now I am interested in it. Also, what is your hosting company?

Answer (score 2):

There is service and it is called an [CDN (Content Delivery Network)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). I personally use and recommend [Cloudflare](http://www.cloudflare.com) as its fast and free to some extent. The implication is that any server based programs detect the IP of the visitor as the IP of the CDN unless you make some changes. This would also help in better site speed.

I you want to set up a reverse proxy, use [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).  Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_%28software%29%E2%80%8E). If you provide your server configuration, I may be able to provide link to a tutorial or two.

Comment: This doesn't answer their question

Comment: I provided a simple alternate solution to the question. My answer is edited to provide a proper answer now.